# Git: Track branch without checking out?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

So, I know you can pull a branch without checking it out by:

```
git fetch origin branchname:branchname
```

**Is there way to also track that branch without checking it out?**
(Normally, this is accomplished by: `git checkout --track origin/branchname` or `git branch -u origin branchname`) Answer could either be a separate command entirely, or a part of the fetch mentioned above.

Comment: `git branch -u <remote/branch> <branch>`

Comment: The `git branch` + `git fetch` commands you listed should accomplish the goal.

Comment: If the branch doesn't exist yet, use `git branch --track <branch> <upstream>`. This creates the branch but doesn't check it out. Note that the order of arguments has the local branch name first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is already embedded in your question, as several commenters note: use `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branchname branchname` (or the shorter version with `-u`).  It might be important to add a few notes here, though.

That's not *pulling a branch* (or, well, maybe it is, since that phrase is not well defined :-) ).  What `git fetch origin branchname:branchname` does is:

- fetch any required commits from origin, and then
- create or update the local branch named *`branchname`* based on what the fetch saw in `origin`'s branch *`branchname`*.

The update, if it is an update, fails if the change to *`branchname`* is not a fast-forward operation.  To force it to succeed in this case, add a force flag: either `--force` or a leading plus sign `+`.

This `git fetch`-based update also fails if *`branchname`* is the currently-checked-out branch, i.e., if `HEAD` is a symbolic reference to that branch.  That is, you can only `git fetch origin branchname:branchname` if that branch name is not actually checked out right now.

Meanwhile, `git branch --set-upstream-to` sets (or overwrites) the *upstream* setting of a (local) branch.  Each local branch can have one *upstream* setting (or no upstream setting).  Having an upstream  makes *other* Git commands—other than `git fetch` that is—easier to use.  Or at least, that's its *purpose;* whether you personally find the result "easier" is a matter of personal preference.  (I've never encountered anyone who found it *harder* though.)

If the local branch already existed and already has an upstream set, you might not want to overwrite the current upstream setting.  You can check by using `git rev-parse`: `branchname@{upstream}` names the current upstream setting of *`branchname`*, or fails if it does not have one, so:

```
if ! git rev-parse $branchname@{upstream} >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/$branchname $branchname
fi
```

will set the upstream if it was unset, but do nothing if it was already set.

Comment: So, I can `git branch -u branchname origin/branchname` even while having `otherbranch` checked out?

Comment: Yes. The order is the other way though: `-u <upstream> <branch>`, not `-u <branch> <upstream>`. You might want to stick with the `--set-upstream-to=<upstream> <branch>` syntax since that's clearer.

Comment: This (`git branch -u remote-branch new-local-name`) doesn't create the local branch; it fails with "fatal: branch 'new-local-name' does not exist". `git branch --track new-local-name remote-branch` worked for creating the tracked branch w/o checking it out.

Comment: @KeithRobertson: Right, `git branch -u` is for *setting* the upstream of an *existing* branch. It's being removed as deprecated anyway though, due to the argument order confusion. If you want to create a branch (not set an existing one) you need what you just said.

Comment: @torek Sure, just pointing out that's not what this answer says. Bullet item 2 says -u will "create or update the local branch". And a later paragraph reads, "If the local branch already existed," implying it works if the branch didn't exist. But I tried it (based on this answer) and it didn't work, and wanted folks to know that. Please consider editing your answer (if SO allows it). E.g. "If the local branch (which must exist) already has...", and remove "create or".

Comment: @KeithRobertson: Ah - it's a bad pronoun reference: the word *that* refers to `git fetch origin branchname:branchname`, not to `git branch --set-upstream-to`, in that bullet point. I'll edit anyway, since it's not clear.